# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Clock()')

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I updated my react native project 0.63 to 0.72.4 and getting issue related to material tab ("@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5") this library because everything working fine getting error on a specific page where I added tab.

Here is my package.json file =>

```
{"name": "Flakex",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.1",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.3",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.11.1",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^11.3.8",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.5.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.32.0",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "firebase": "^10.4.0",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.72.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-awesome-card-io": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1301.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^6.0.5",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-credit-card-input-view": "^0.0.7",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^3.2.10",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.16",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.6.0",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "8.6.3",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-geocoder": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^12.2.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-location": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "https://github.com/noway/react-native-material-dropdown",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.25.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "^3.0.16",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "rn-faded-scrollview": "^1.0.10",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.23.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.65.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

After project upgraded I compile with material older version and
getting same error so I upgraded the lib and getting same issue in iOS.

[Here is an image of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLeOB.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. Check Compatibility Issues
   Review the release notes of the libraries used in your project, especially the `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs` library, to ensure compatibility with React Native 0.72.4.
   Sometimes, new versions of React Native might introduce breaking changes that affect how certain libraries function.
2. Upgrade Dependencies
   Ensure all dependencies, including `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs` and its related packages, are updated to versions compatible with React Native 0.72.4.
   Use the appropriate versions that are explicitly compatible with React Native 0.72.4. You might need to check for any specific versions or migration guides mentioned in the library's release notes.
3. Check for Deprecated Code
   Look for any deprecated methods or components in the `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs` library that might have been replaced or removed in the newer version. Update your code accordingly.
4. Clear Caches and Rebuild
   Clear the React Native cache by running: `npx react-native start --reset-cache`

Rebuild the project using:

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

or:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that one of your package might be outdated. I was getting the same error while upgrading from **RN 0.64.0** to **RN 0.69.12** and upgrading the package version worked for me.

Solution that worked for me:

I had only upgraded react-native-reanimated package and later on when I upgraded the other package and repeating the gradle steps it got resolved.

**react-native-reanimated** - 1.13.1 to 3.6.1

**react-native-tab-view** - 2.11.0 to 3.5.2